# How to hook to content profile edit form validation

Tags: 6, forms

I try the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function mymod_profile_node_form_validate($node,&$form) {   
  firep($form, 'form');  
}
```

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to add a custom validation to a form 1st you're going to have to modified the form and inject your validation.

So 1st lets infect our validation into a form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'name_of_the_form_we_want_to_alter') {
    // Notice that we're appending to the array, we not replacing, this is to keep the regular validation function.
    $form['#validate'][] = 'name_of_our_custom_validation_function';
  }
}
```

Now we need to add out validation function:

```
function name_of_our_custom_validation_function($form, &$form_state) {
 //We do all our processing in here.
}
```

This should cover most use cases in Drupal 6 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work as it is not a hook.

Try `hook_form_alter()` to edit form so that `$form['#validate']` can be defined.

```
$form['#validate'] = !empty($form['#validate']) ? $form['#validate'] + array('mycustom_validate_handler') : array('mycustom_validate_handler');
```

Then define your function

```
function mycustom_validate_handler($form, $form_state){
     // Do your validation.
}
```