# Depended CCK Fields

Tags: entities

There are two Fields, Image and Video
Users have to use only one field, image or video.
The problem is how do I remove video field if user upload a image ?
is there any custom validation for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Conditional fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module can do this. It allows to set up conditions and dependencies between multiple files (for example, only show field X if field Y is filled/checked).

Comment: I'm already using Conditional fields but it's only show and hide fields. if user upload image and edit the node and upload a new video both of them is allowed to upload. I need a validation of this.

Comment: I guess the problem here is that images/files are kinda special. Once you've uploaded a file, there is no form field anymore so your conditional field rule does not match anymore. Maybe you can inverse it (Instead of hide the video field if image is filled, change it to *show* the video field as long as the image field is  empty). Untested. You could also ask *that* (how to make a rule that works for this) as a question.

Comment: @kLezer This is a perfect example why you need to put all relevant information in the question and explain more what your problem is. I'd have been able to give you the comment above as an answer to your question initially... With the given information, there was no way for me to know that you are already using conditional fields.

Comment: Thank you Berdir, I'll create a custom module for validation. first trial was successful...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `hook_form_alter` to add your own validate handler to your content type form. For example code [View this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5388).